# Getting Null in request.getAttribute(..) in Struts 2

Tags: java, parameters, struts2

Setting Attribute

```
public class VoucherApproverListAction extends ActionSupport implements
SessionAware, ServletRequestAware, Preparable {
private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    public HttpServletRequest getServletRequest() {
        return servletRequest;
    }


    @Override
    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
        this.servletRequest=servletRequest;
    }

public void prepare() throws Exception {
servletRequest.setAttribute("id",tCaseVouchrDto.getId());
}
}
```

Getting Attribute

```
 public class VoucherAction extends ActionSupport implements
    SessionAware, ServletRequestAware, Preparable {
    private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

        public HttpServletRequest getServletRequest() {
            return servletRequest;
        }


        @Override
        public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
            this.servletRequest=servletRequest;
        }

    public void prepare() throws Exception {
   String paramValue = (String)servletRequest.getAttribute("id");
        logger.info("@-----Id===-----@" + paramValue);
    }
    }
```

From VoucherApproverListAction  action class after success ,it is redirected to VoucherAction  action class Getting `null` in paramValue

Comment: Also, why ate you using the request to get parameters anyway? You should almost never need to access the request directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From VoucherApproverListAction action class after success ,it is
>   redirected to VoucherAction action class

This is the problem, request attributes are lost if you send redirect. You need to pass a parameter or save it in the session before the next request.